# What's that song at the end of Dexter S08E08?

Tags: soundtrack, dexter

Dexter comes home, hears the *Make your own kind of music* song, then sees the dead kid and dramatic melody starts playing. How is it called?

Comment: Dead kid...episode 8. Which season are you referring to?

Comment: Im guessing hes referring to Zac from the season 8 episode "Are we there yet?"

Comment: @Travis ohh...that's a spoiler for me ;)

Comment: @AnkitSharma Sorry Ankit, I added the spoiler word in the title.

Comment: @evening Don't do that. Spoilers are absolutely no problem in question bodies and the title isn't a spoiler anyway. Adding a *"[SPOILER]"* to question titles is highly discouraged. *Ankit* wasn't refering to the question being a spoiler but to *Travis*'s comment. What was more of a confusion was probably the use of "episode" instead of "season", which if used properly would have stopped *Ankit* from reading the question at all. But I'm not acquainted enough with *Dexter* to change that "episode" to "season" in the title. Feel free to do this if this was what you actually meant.

Comment: Fixed the title as per comments, please correct if i am wrong.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Are you sure he meant episode 8 of season 8 and not just season 8?

Comment: @AnkitSharma Forget what I said, you're probably right given that episode 8 was the newest at the time of the question and has the title that *Travis* named in his comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The track is actually 'Argentina - Daniel Licht' which is Track 10 on Dexter - Season 7 (Music From The Original Series). Listen from around 30-35 seconds in and you'll recognise it within about 10 seconds! Find it here: http://open.spotify.com/track/40Y80ukppQKlFRuiVta4Ck or https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/dexter-season-7-music-from/id684236034

Answer (score 3):

The "Make your own kind of music song" is [Make Your Own Kind of Music](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_Your_Own_Kind_of_Music_%28song%29) performed by [Mama Cass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cass_Elliot) (A.K.A Cass Elliot). I believe the song playing when Dexter is throwing Zach's body into the water is a never before, or at least rarely played part of the [Dexter Blood Theme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexter%3a_Music_from_the_Showtime_Original_Series) by [Daniel Licht](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Licht).

Comment: Wait, do you mean the one that's playing when he throws the body in the water? If so, I think that's part of normal blood theme music they play in the background of a lot of episodes.

Comment: I don't think they had ever played that song ever before...

Comment: When they write a song for television, they don't always play the whole song. They usually only play the same part of it over and over again. I believe you heard a new portion of the song.

Comment: Makes senses @druciferre

Comment: and thanks druciferre.....you are the man.. i was looking for this song or a long time.. you made my day..